# Navigation menu (responsive) and cols not viewing correctly on mobile device

Tags: android, css, mobile, navigationbar, responsive

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 960px) {
  .flexslider {
    margin-top: 100px;
  }

  .main-header {
    padding: 15px 0;
  }
  .main-header .logo {
    margin-top: 20px;
  }

  .service-item, .team-member {
    margin-bottom: 50px;
  }

  .our-skills {
    margin-top: 60px;
  }

  .flex-caption {
    top: 20%;
  }
  .flex-caption h2 {
    font-size: 24px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }
  .flex-caption p {
    font-size: 14px;
    width: 70%;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }

  .left-header, .right-header {
    text-align: center;
  }
}
```

I think something is wrong with the mobile viewing of my 'main-header' and 'body header'. Having issues with the responsive menu nav bar and my main company logo .png inside the main-header container not sizing properly. This makes my 'home' 'about' 'vinnies' etc nav section run into my logo viewing on tablet. Then when viewing on mobile, the three line navigation bar shows way to the right when viewing on mobile devices. When I click on the three line nav bar it does not show my navigation links-not clickable. Also, my company logo (.png) for St. Vincent de Paul doesn't seem to be resize to mobile media screen. Then the body header links end up all over the place. Looking for help so this looks okay on mobile. Website is: www.svdpplymouth.org -Thank you for any help!

```css
.top-header {
  background: #191970;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 0;
  z-index: 1000
}
.top-header .left-header span {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 8px 20px 0 0;
}
.top-header .left-header span i {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.top-header .right-header ul.social-icons li {
  display: inline-block;
}
.top-header .right-header ul.social-icons li a {
  color: white;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
  border: 2px solid white;
  -webkit-border-radius: 16px;
  border-radius: 16px;
  margin: 0 8px;
}
.top-header .right-header ul.social-icons li a:hover {
  background-color: white;
  color: #191970;
}
.main-header {
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 9999;
  padding: 10px 0;
  background: white;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(1, 1, 1, 0.15);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(1, 1, 1, 0.15);
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(1, 1, 1, 0.15);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
.main-header .logo {
  margin-top: 2px;
}
.main-header .logo h1 {
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.main-header .logo h1 a {
  color: #444444;
}
.main-header .menu {
  margin-top: 35px;
}
.main-header .menu ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 5px;
}
.main-header .menu ul li a {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #777777;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 4px 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
.main-header .menu ul li a.current {
  background: #191970;
  color: white;
}
.main-header-shrink {
  padding: 10px 0;
  top: 0;
}
#body-header {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 4px 0;
  background: #b7dd33;
}
#body-header .nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 0px;
}
#body-header .nav ul li a {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 8px;
}
#body-header .nav li a:hover {
  background-color: #191970;
  color: #ffffff;
}
.responsive-menu {
  position: relative;
  top: -20px;
}
.responsive-menu .toggle-menu {
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #191970;
}
.responsive-menu .menu {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 52px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #191970;
}
.responsive-menu .menu ul li {
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d1601c;
  margin: 0;
}
.responsive-menu .menu ul li:last-child {
  border-bottom: 0;
}
.responsive-menu .menu ul li a {
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  display: block;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
}
.responsive-menu .menu ul li a.current {
  background-color: #444444;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <div id="header">
    <div class="site-header">
      <div class="top-header">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
              <div class="left-header">
                <span><i class="fa fa-phone"></i>920-892-4913</span>
                <span><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i><a href="mailto:info@svdpplymouth.org">info@svdpplymouth.org</a></span>
                <span><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>M-F 9AM-7PM SAT 9AM-5PM</span>
              </div>
              <!-- /.left-header -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.col-md-6 -->
            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
              <div class="right-header text-right">
                <ul class="social-icons">
                  <li>
                    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/?q=#/svdpplymouth" class="fa fa-facebook"></a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a href="https://www.instagram.com/svdpply/" class="fa fa-instagram"></a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a href="https://www.pinterest.com/svdpplymouth/" class="fa fa-pinterest"></a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a href="https://twitter.com/svdp_ply" class="fa fa-twitter"></a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a href="https://www.youtube.com/my_videos?o=U" class="fa fa-youtube"></a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
              <!-- /.left-header -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.col-md-6 -->
          </div>
          <!-- /.row -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.container -->
      </div>
      <!-- /.top-header -->
      <div class="main-header">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
              <div class="logo">
                <h1><img src="images/SVDPlogotitle.png"></h1>
              </div>
              <!-- /.logo -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.col-md-4 -->
            <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-6">
              <div class="menu text-right hidden-sm hidden-xs">
                <ul>
                  <li><a href="http://www.svdpplymouth.org/index.html">Home</a>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="http://www.svdpplymouth.org/about.html">About</a>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="http://www.svdpplymouth.org/vinnies.html">Vinnies</a>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="http://www.svdpplymouth.org/outreach.html">Outreach</a>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="http://www.svdpplymouth.org/crossroads.html">CrossRoads</a>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="http://www.svdpplymouth.org/contact.html">Contact</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
              <!-- /.menu -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.col-md-4 -->
          </div>
          <!-- /.col-md-8 -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.row -->
        <div class="responsive-menu text-right visible-xs visible-sm">
          <a href="#" class="toggle-menu fa fa-bars"></a>
          <div class="menu">
            <ul>
              <li><a href="http://www.svdpplymouth.org/index.html">Home</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="http://www.svdpplymouth.org/about.html">About</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="http://www.svdpplymouth.org/vinnies.html">Vinnies</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="http://www.svdpplymouth.org/outreach.html">Outreach</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="http://www.svdpplymouth.org/crossroads.html">CrossRoads</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="http://www.svdpplymouth.org/contact.html">Contact</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <!-- /.menu -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.responsive-menu -->
      </div>
      <!-- /.container -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.header -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.site-header -->
  </div>
  <!-- /#home -->

  <div id="body-header">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-7">
          <div class="nav left header">
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#history">History</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#svdpply">SVDP Plymouth</a>
                </li<li><a href="#volunteer">Volunteer</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#stew">Stewardship</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#vop">Voice of the Poor</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#resources">Resources</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-5">
          <div class="nav right-header text-right">
            <ul>
              <li class="fa fa-hand-o-right"><a href="http://www.svdpplymouth.org/about.html#volunteer" style="font-size:12px;">Volunteer</a>
              </li>
              <li class="fa fa-heart-o">
                <a style="font-size:12px;" href=" crossroads.html ">Donations</a></li>
       <li class="fa fa-check-square-o "><a href="http://www.svdpplymouth.org/outreach.html#outreachapps " style="font-size:12px; ">Applications-Forms</a></li>
      </ul>
     </div> 
    </div>
   </div>
  </div> 
 </div> 
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your media query just add one more line for Menu

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 960px) {
.main-header .logo h1 img{width:100%;}
.responsive-menu .toggle-menu{font-size:40px;}
.responsive-menu .toggle-menu{top: -16px;right: 20px;position: relative;}
.responsive-menu .menu{z-index:99;top:0}
}
```